# Azure DevOps migration tool attached child links

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-migration-tools

I'm in the process of migrating data from one server to another. It works perfectly except the newley imported work items in the new location have an issue.

When selecting one, it shows an exclamtion of "the value for field 'Activated Date' must be empty. If I remove the activation date, it will only jump to a new warning similar. On examination on the source data, there is child links to the work items which the devops tool is not pulling over.

Is there a way to specify this in the config file at all to include the child links when migrating?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

The tool pulls over all work items within scope for QueryBit and processes all Links that are between those items. The usual reason for items not being brought across is that they were over in scope to be processed.

Try updating the QueryBit to be more inclusive.